# how to test develop facebook app with google app engine on local machine

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine

Is it possible to develop facebook using google app engine locally, without having to upload application every time I change it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you are getting API error 191 when you try to access the Facebook API from the dev appserver?

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

If you are developing on your localhost, you can set the 'Site Domain' field in your facebook [app settings](https://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php) to `(appname).appspot.com` and then edit the [HOSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file on your system.

In my environment I just entered:

```
127.0.0.1   devlocal.(appname).appspot.com
```

As long as the browser's URL matches `*.(appname).appspot.com`, it will work.

Comment: This (i.e. using HOSTS) is a very neat idea which actually applies not only to Facebook, but many other sites (redirect after transaction in PayPal comes to my mind as an example). Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: I had this issue just yesterday, in fact!

Comment: @justinmorgan What about the :8080? without it i'm getting an error page, and when I add it at the end of the url facebook still gives me error code 191

Answer (score 2):

You could set the Website field in your Facebook app settings to `http://localhost:XXXX` or `http://127.0.0.1:XXXX` for development and then change it over to the actual once ready for deployment. This worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a couple years ago and wrote a long article about how I solved it for my needs.

http://www.upwithabang.com/articles/GAE-facebook-win7.html

It covers the setting up of an Apache server on your laptop then telling Facebook and the GAE to behave as if it hosted on a production server. This solves the pain of constant uploads for testing every little change.

Hopefully this is helpful to someone, if not a little late.